# Are causal anti-realism and metaphysical realism compatible?

Tags: metaphysics, causality

Could the existence of a mind-independent reality be compatible with believing that causal relations aren't real? If so, how could the latter be justified? Could one make an instrumentalist case like in the case of scientific anti-realism (could you say that causal relations are just made up as instrumental to predictions similarly to how a scientific antirealist says scientific things are)? How could the causal anti-realist explain the existence of anything?

Comment: Yes, this is called Humeanism about causation and many realists are Humeans. They believe that reality exhibits regularities that we codify into laws, but metaphysical "causing" as such is just a useful (or not) fiction. Objects exist, events exist, laws that govern them exist, but not "causing" of one by another. Russell [once called](https://philpapers.org/browse/causal-eliminativism) causality "*a relic of a bygone age, surviving, like the monarchy, only because it is erroneously supposed to do no harm*", although he moderated his language somewhat later.

Comment: @edelex The standard assumption in philosophy and science is the existence of a mind-independent external word. Why should one assume that causality in our world is not real? - It seems to me speculation just for the sake of speculation.

Comment: in a "mind-independent reality" ....  who/where/what can/is "believe"?, what is/means "causal" and what are "relations"? no, in a "mind-independent reality" only (pure+massive+motion-less) sh#t can "be there"